# Parallelize and monitor tasks with ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have a function/task `void task()` that needs to be called about 4-6 million times.
I want to parallelize this operation over threads in a thread pool.
I do not care about the return value of the tasks so I can avoid messing around with `Future<T>`.
I want to periodically poll the status of how the threads are coming along.  The status is simply how many invocations of `task()` returned cleanly and how many threw an exception.

Here's what I came up with:

```java
class Test {
    AtomicInteger success = new AtomicInteger(0);
    AtomicInteger failed = new AtomicInteger(0);
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1_000_000);

    private void start() {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
          executorService.execute(this::task);
        }
        while (!countDownLatch.await(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
          log("Success: %d Failed: %d", success.get(), failed.get());
        }
        log("===================== Final tally =====================");
        log("Success: %d Failed: %d", success.get(), failed.get());
        executorService.shutdown();
    }

    private void task() {
        try {
           doSomeStuff();
           success.incrementAndGet()
        } catch(Exception e) {
           failed.incrementAndGet();
        }
        countDownLatch.countDown();
    }
}
```

Two `AtomicInteger` that the threads use to record successes or failures and a `CountDownLatch` that the "monitor" thread uses to check on the progress.

Is there a more idiomatic way to do this? Some thing that doesn't involve submitting millions of `Runnable` lambdas to the `ExecutorService` perhaps?

I could put the whole thing in an

```java
IntStream.range(0, 1_000_000).parallelStream().map(...).groupBy(...)
```

but I won't be able to monitor the progress.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use stream as you proposed, you can move your monitoring part into another thread like this:

```
new Thread(()->{  
 while (!countDownLatch.await(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
          log("Success: %d Failed: %d", success.get(), failed.get());
        }
        log("===================== Final tally =====================");
        log("Success: %d Failed: %d", success.get(), failed.get());
}).start()

IntStream.range(0, 1_000_000).parallelStream().map(...).groupBy(...)
```